# Modify Notification Message When Profile Updated

Tags: hooks, profiles

I have added new fields on the user profile page.

I want to display a message that says: "It's good ... or not"

I couldn't find a hook in the WordPress codex.

I don't want to use a plugin only my own code I want change this code :

```
<div id="message" class="updated">
    <p><strong>Updated profile </strong></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use a gettext filter as there are no hooks or filters associated with your request.

```
function custom_user_message($translation, $text){
    if('Profile updated.' == $text){
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        $foo_condition = ''; //Do some checking here for user custom field
        if(!$foo_condition)
            return $text.' Custom Message';
    }
    return $translation;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'custom_user_message', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it could help others. There is actually an action to use with this: admin_notices. [Here is the link to it on the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices)

Here is how you would use it:

```
function my_admin_notice(){
    echo '<div class="updated">
       <p>Aenean eros ante, porta commodo lacinia.</p>
    </div>';
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```